# AngularJS Attach Scope Function in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltipster

I have an AngularJS Directive that attaches [jQuery Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) to elements in a `ng-repeat` like so:

View:

```
div.chat-wrapper
    ul.chat-messages
        li(ng-repeat='chat in chatmessages' chat-tooltip)
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('chatTooltip',
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                    scope.mute = function() {
                        console.log('hello world');
                    };

                    $(el).tooltipster({
                        content: $('<button ng-click="mute()" class="btn">Mute</button>'),
                        position: 'left',
                        positionTracker: true,
                        trigger: 'hover',
                        interactive: true,
                        autoClose: false
                    });
                }
            };
        }
);
```

I want to call the `mute()` function defined in the `scope` or `$scope` - ? Since the plugin adds the HTML content in the directive - I'm not sure what I need to do?

Comment: what happens when you click the button?

Comment: do console.log in mute, to check if its being called, and try `el.tooltipster` rather than $(el)

Comment: @voroninp nothing happens, @HarishR tried it no response? I've seen stuff about using `$compile` to reset things ?

Answer (score 1):

I can try to guess.

The problem here is that your html is parsed by jQuery. And not by angular's parser.

So until you provide any customization and are calling predefined method I advise you to create an element for content:

```
var button $(....);
```

Then pass this value to the `content` option and subscibe to button's click event imperatively with `button.on('click')` method.

Answer (score 1):

please, take a look on this question/answer:

[How to replace a html content with jsf reRender or ajax load, and rebind the new DOM with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131078/how-to-replace-a-html-content-with-jsf-rerender-or-ajax-load-and-rebind-the-new)

It's show how to "rebind" angularjs after a jquery change, and how to call a angularjs function from jQuery.

But, to be short, you can call a angularjs function from scope with a code like this (identifying your controller by an id):

```
$('#idFromMyController').scope().myFunction();
```