# How to reload a custom directive in AngularJS after a Jquery's replaceWith?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to reset an input element and the way i used to do this is by utilizing JQuery's replaceWith method.
Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">attach.file = {{attach.file.name}} <br>
    <input type="file" id="file_" file-model="attach.file" file-model>
    <br>
    <button clear>Clear input</button>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('clear', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                control = $("#file_");
                control.replaceWith(control.val('').clone(true));
                scope.attach.file = null;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.attach = {
        file: null
    };
});
```

The problem is that after use it, my custom directive, which sets the file in my angular model, is not called anymore.

I'm not familiar with neither JQuery nor AngularJS.
Is there a way to reload the custom directive?

Here is a fiddle for this scenario:  http://jsfiddle.net/hjqsjrro/4/

Thanks

Comment: This is how I would get there - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/1msvvjan/#base  -  but I would probably go straight to https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload to upload files.

Comment: @Dylan, your jsfiddle works nice if the input file is cleared by its own controller. But i need that the outer control clear it (in this case, MyCtrl).

Comment: @Dylan, The real problem is that after submit, the outer control needs to clean this input, besides it cleans the model object, the input file is not cleared.
Here is a jsfiddle simulating it: http://jsfiddle.net/714erk89/

I had to add an reference in the parent scope because i don't know another to access the child scopes.

The ng-file-upload gives me the same problem after the refresh.

Comment: This seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/49Lbzcwc/

Comment: @Dylan, this solution works perfectly either in the inner directive or in outer controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a example to resolve this question.

You could try to compile the DOM, and the events will returns to execute. Please, look for:

[How to replace a html content with jsf reRender or ajax load, and rebind the new DOM with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131078/how-to-replace-a-html-content-with-jsf-rerender-or-ajax-load-and-rebind-the-new/27131087#27131087)

Comment: In your example, we need to recompile it with the instructions '($compile($el))($scope);
 $scope.$apply();'
After, a replaceWith, i tried to recompile with '($compile(file_))(scope);'
but it seems to not been working. What am i missing ?
Here's the updated jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hjqsjrro/6/

Comment: I look your code. You clear the content of #file_ with file_.val(''), and after, you try to recompile with $(compile(file_)... but, at this moment, there are nothing to compile.

Comment: I thought that the clone method would rebuild the element identically.