# compile html string with ng-click inside foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a tree structure that has tons of items, so it is working very slow. I am trying to rewrite it in javascript to obtain a bit more performance. But I am stuck at the `ng-click`:

HTML:

```
<jstree initialstructure="vm.initialStructure" get-child-nodes="vm.getChildNodes()"></jstree>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('app.jstree')
    .directive('jstree', Jstree);

Jstree.$inject = ['$compile'];

function Jstree($compile) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'JstreeController',
        controllerAs: 'jst',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            initialstructure: '=',
            getChildNodes: '&'
        },
        link:  function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('initialstructure', function (items) {
                    if (items) {
                       var html = "";
                       angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                           html = html.concat('<li ui-tree-node>' + item.title);
                           var selectedNodeCls = item.selected ? 'selected-node' : '';
                           html = html.concat('<div ui-tree-handle ng-click="alert(item);" class="' + selectedNodeCls + '" tooltip="' + item.title + '">');
                           html = html.concat('</div>');
                           html = html.concat('</li>');
                      });
                      element.html(html);
                      element = $compile(element)(scope);
                   }
                   scope.alert = function(item) {
                         console.log(item); //this is undefined, obviously because it is not on the scope
                   }
               });
            }
    };
    return directive;
  }
})();
```

how could this be solved?

Comment: can you put some more code. I'm trying to reproduce the error, and i have to make a lot of assumptions on what your code looks like.

Comment: @DarinCardin done, but it's nothing else than what I wrote the first time. Just a directive with that code inside. the relevant problem is that ng-click, what the technique is to make that work

Comment: You can try to rebind the replaced html to angular. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131078/how-to-replace-a-html-content-with-jsf-rerender-or-ajax-load-and-rebind-the-new

Comment: hm, at first, you already is doing the rebind. You can compare the codes to have an idea of the problem.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo if only item would be on scope

Answer (score 0):

I have done something, I don't know if it is the cleanest way, atm it works:

```
angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
         ............
         html = html.concat('<div ui-tree-handle ng-click="alert(initialstructure[' + index + ']);" class="' + selectedNodeCls + '" tooltip="' + item.title + '">');
         ..........
```